# How many ether user eventually get after trading in this smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, ether, etherscan

I'm exploring method `trade` of [this smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#code) that looks like the following:

```
  function trade(address tokenGet, uint amountGet, address tokenGive, uint amountGive, uint expires, uint nonce, address user, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint amount) {
      //amount is in amountGet terms
      bytes32 hash = sha256(this, tokenGet, amountGet, tokenGive, amountGive, expires, nonce);
      if (!(
              (orders[user][hash] || ecrecover(sha3("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash), v, r, s) == user) &&
              block.number <= expires &&
              safeAdd(orderFills[user][hash], amount) <= amountGet
          )) throw;
      tradeBalances(tokenGet, amountGet, tokenGive, amountGive, user, amount);
      orderFills[user][hash] = safeAdd(orderFills[user][hash], amount);
      Trade(tokenGet, amount, tokenGive, amountGive * amount / amountGet, user, msg.sender);
  }
```

Could you please answer the following questions:

1. What's difference between `amountGet` and `amount` arguments?
2. How can I eventually know how many `ETH` user got when selling [ARC token](https://etherscan.io/token/0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5) in this [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x48332867933b2d06e1fe38923f8501dcf3b2d3c6e21d012b562a510a5417a5e9) ? Does `amountGive` give me this value?

Decoded input of this transaction is:

```
  inputs: [
        '0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5',
        '2500000000000000000000',
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        '13775000000000000000',
        '3156959',
        '3696351802',
        '0xd8eeda4ee2657bb267bc35c1d60babdc5aedd269',
        '28',
        'b4bf0dcd37ca73bd5abce9532b033dcc6427be160683de113efca41320c27f3e',
        '78799d84040e5c245828b1b531ef97e1af124946f4dc1db5a20cf28a7073b269',
        '726181804936299500000'
    ]
```

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `amountGet` is how much the maker of the order is willing to buy. `amount` is how much the taker of the order is willing to sell.
2. `amount` is the amount that gets traded. `amountGet` is only used to locate the order by its hash. The amount of `tokenGive` (ETH in this case) that the transaction sender gets is `amount * amountGive / amountGet`.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, But still is the questions about how much eth the maker got after this trade? How to calculate it based on transaction input data in my question?

Comment: it should be `amount * amountGive / amountGet`. You can match the corresponding input values to those arguments.

Comment: Are you sure that `amount * amountGive / amountGet` gives me `ETH` ?

Comment: As far as I know yes. You have any doubts?

Comment: Normally it should give you the amount of `tokenGive`. In this particular example it's 0x0 which is ETH.

Comment: @Erik line 278 here https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol

Comment: @Erik did it help?

Comment: sorry for stupid question, is my example of transaction selling ETH or buying ETH?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73243/discussion-between-erik-and-medvedev1088).